# Sending REST response in plain text or JSON?

Tags: json, api, rest

When creating a REST API, if I return data in JSON format for GET requests, is it a good practice to also send responses for POST, PUT, DELETE, and error messages in JSON too or plain text will suffice?

For example:

For POST request where I need to return the new ID of the newly added record (i.e. just the new auto increment value in database), should the response still be in JSON or just plain text like "1" or "2" for example.

Same goes for PUT or DELETE request where I need to say "OK" or "Accepted", as well error messages like "Bad Request", "Not Found", etc.

Plain text or JSON?

Comment: I'd say JSON just to get things consistent, even if you return simple values now, that may change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the client-provided [`Accept` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.1) to let the client control what content type they want.  If no header is provided, then use a sensible default and **always** include a [`Content-Type` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.17) in the response.  See the [Content Negotiation section of RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-12) for more details.

Comment: The choices are still up to me right? (e.g., I only want JSON or plain text, no XML) or XML is also required?

Comment: Nothing is really _required_.  The client can ask for `Accept: application/foo` and you can respond with `Content-Type: text/json`.  The `Accept` header is a preference from the view of the client and the `Content-Type` header is an assertion that the enclosed entity body meets the requirements of a specific MIME type.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, returning just "1" is valid JSON.  It's just not a array or associative mapping.

For OK and Accepted, you can just use the HTTP status codes for those.   No body is really necessary.

Comment: According to [RFC4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627), JSON-Text is defined as either an array or an object.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the ability the client has.

Of course, you don't actually have to choose one or the other: you can use content-type negotiation to return a different representation depending on the user-agent's acceptance list.